# SQLite: compare dates from columns

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I'm working with SQLite on an Android application.

I want to select the next 5 days from a table that has only day and month columns, but I'm unable to do it with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE ('2018-' || month || '-' || day) 
   BETWEEN date('now', '+1 days') AND date('now', '+5 days')
```

But when I add a zero before month and day, it correctly selects the (mars) rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE ('2018-0' || month || '-0' || day) 
   BETWEEN date('now', '+1 days') AND date('now', '+5 days')
```

But this won't work for months like 10, 11 and 12, and the same for days.
What should I do?

**EDIT 1**

Table columns : id (integer) day (integer) month (integer)

Second query results:

```
id - day - month
3 - 10 - 3
4 - 11 - 3
5 - 12 - 3
```

Comment: please define the columns of table_name and sample data too. Thanks.

Comment: I've added them, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the month is expecting to be in MM format but your data is length 1 (3 - March). I fix your query by prefixing 0 in case the month is 1-9.
I did the same for days. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
where ('2018-' || substr('0'||month, -2, 2) || '-' || substr('0'||day, -2, 2))
BETWEEN date('now', '+1 day') AND date('now', '+5 day');
```

Result:

```
ID  day month
3   10  3
4   11  3
5   12  3
```